# How to configure FluentD (EFK) with Filebeat?

Tags: kibana, elastic-stack, fluentd, filebeat, efk

I have configured ELK-stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash, and Kibana) cluster for centralized logging system with Filebeat. Now I have been asked to reconfigure to EFK (Elasticsearch, FluentD, and Kibana) with Filebeat. I have disabled the Logstash and Installed FluentD, But I'm not able to configure FluentD with Filebeat. I have installed [FluentD plugin](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-beats) for Filebeat and modified `/etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf`, but it seems not working.

td-agent.conf

```
<source>
  @type beats
  tag record['@metadata']['beat']
  port 5044
  bind 0.0.0.0
</source>

<match *.**>
  @type copy
   <store>
    #@type file
    @type elasticsearch_dynamic
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix ${tag_parts[0]}
    type_name ${record['type']}
  </store>
  <store>
    @type file
    logstash_format true
    logstash_prefix ${tag_parts[0]}
    type_name ${record['type']}
    path /var/log/td-agent/data_logs.*.log
 </store>
</match>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you give a try using this ?https://en-designetwork.daichi703n.com/entry/2017/07/09/filebeat-fluentd-tag-routing

Answer (score 0):

A source is an input not an output in fluentd you would want a match with the corresponding fluentd tags that match to be shipped to filebeats then out to Elastic.